# Local DNS for 3 VPN connected sites

Tags: vpn, dns

I currently have 3 R Pis running Dnsmasq at 3 sites providing local name resolution. Each site is connected to the other two with LAN-to-LAN VPNs. Each site also has dial-in VPN access. I would like to add remote site name resolution but have been so far unsuccessful in configuring this.

Current config at each site:

```
    domain-needed
    bogus-priv
    no-resolv
    server="local isp dns"
    cache-size=1000
```

Each DNS has a hosts file with all local and remote hosts.

Currently "PING 'remote host'" results in "Ping request could not find host 'remote host', Please..."

"PING 'remote IP'" works, ok.

However, "dig 'remote host' A +noall +answer" elicits its IP address.

My aim is to have the Windows Explorer network neighborhood display all hosts.

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. You should ask this question on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions).

Comment: What are these statements for current config at each site mean? Are all sites continuous connected, or are they dynamically dialed in when needed (this will complicate things a lot)?

Comment: I have now asked this in Superuser as requested by @M. Rostami. I thank him for the correction of "ip" to "IP" and the typo of "successful". However, there are two sides to "the pond" and on this side "neighborhood" is spelt "neighbourhood". I have never understood why we adopted the misspelling of "programme". Presumably "program" does not cause any confusion on your side.